# Navigation hover elements using jQuery lavalamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you see [this website](http://cavc.ac.uk)

When you hover over the child unordered lists the bottom border dosn't align properly. Only on the 14-19 does this happen.

Here is the code:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.lavaLamp = function(o) {
    o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, click: function(){} }, o || {});
    return this.each(function() {
        var me = $(this), noop = function(){},
            $back = $('<li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>').appendTo(me),
            $li = $("li", this), 
            curr = $("li.active", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("active")[0];

        $li.not(".back").hover(function() {
            move(this);
        }, noop);

        $(this).hover(noop, function() {
            move(curr);
        });

        $li.click(function(e) {
            setCurr(this);
            return o.click.apply(this, [e, this]);
        });

       setCurr(curr);

        function setCurr(el) {
            $back.css({ "left": el.offsetLeft+"px", "width": el.offsetWidth+"px", "border-bottom-color": $(el).css("border-bottom-color") });
            curr = el;
        };
        function move(el) {
            $back.each(function() {
                $(this).dequeue(); }
            ).animate({
                width: el.offsetWidth,
                left: el.offsetLeft
            }, o.speed, o.fx).css({"border-bottom-color": $(el).css("border-bottom-color")});
        };
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Could someone please explain what is going on here and how I can ammend the above to work.

Thanks

Comment: I have opened that page in 3 browsers but don't see what the problem is.

Comment: When you hover over a menu item the bottom-border moves to the correct item, then move the cursor over the dropdown and see that the bottom-border expands but not as it should. 14-19 is the only item that works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function move(el) {
  $el=$(el);
  $back.each(function() {
    $(this).dequeue(); 
 }).animate({
   width: $el.width(),
   left: $el.offset().left
   }, o.speed, o.fx).css({"border-bottom-color": $el.css("border-bottom-color")});
};
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this dosn't seem to have fixed the problem. it's now starting half way and expanding too far to the right. The trick would be to get the left position correct. It starts off at 199 using your code above.

Comment: Sorted. Changed this line: left: $el.offset().left - 199. Thanks